# Configure Netbeans to compile code in C ++

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am trying to compile a basic code in C++ using the Netbeans 11.1 IDE. For this I have installed Cygwin tools that incorporate the compiler, make tool and debugger.

In Netbeans I installed the plugin to be able to develop in C/C++ and testing with C I have no problem.

[image]

When writing the following code, I note that the IDE shows two errors:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

1) In the instruction #include the IDE indicates the message "Cannot find include file ".
2) The IDE also marks the std identifier as wrong saying "Unable to resolve identifier std"

Comment: Looks like you might be compiling your code as C, not C++?

Comment: you need to use `g++` not `gcc` to compile c++ code